# PHPUnit very odd results

Tags: phpunit, equality

`assertEquals()` fails when comparing `'0'` to `false`, but passes when comparing `'1'` to `true`

```
$this->assertEquals( '0', false ); // fails
$this->assertEquals( '1', true );  // passes
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

A string is not false, nor is it true.  PHPUnit does a complete equal, so even 1 does not equal true.

PHPUnit uses the === (triple equals) operator on comparison, so therefore, only TRUE === TRUE, not 1.

Comment: Why does the second `assertEquals()` pass?

Comment: Remember the order of the variables.  '1' is the expected result.  The '1' is a string.  You are evaluating a TRUE to be a string. This is passing as per @STLMikey in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit has very complex assertion system. For this case there would be use `PHPUnit_Framework_Comparator_Scalar` class, which has this code:

```
public function assertEquals($expected, $actual, $delta = 0, $canonicalize = FALSE, $ignoreCase = FALSE)
{
    $expectedToCompare = $expected;
    $actualToCompare = $actual;

    // always compare as strings to avoid strange behaviour
    // otherwise 0 == 'Foobar'
    if (is_string($expected) || is_string($actual)) {
        $expectedToCompare = (string)$expectedToCompare;
        $actualToCompare = (string)$actualToCompare;
    // omitted
    }

    if ($expectedToCompare != $actualToCompare) {

        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure(
        // omitted
        );
    }
}
```

If one of values is string they both converted to string.

```
var_dump((string)false); // string(0) ""
var_dump((string)true); // string(1) "1"
```